# Create new column in R dataframe with values in other columns

Tags: r, dataframe

My R dataframe's headers include Forward, Backward, SideLeft, SideRight, and the new column I am trying to create is the Direction column.

The columns started with just TRUE/FALSE values, and I converted the TRUE values into the header names and made them all characters.

```
df[df==TRUE] <- colnames(df)[which(df==TRUE, arr.ind=TRUE)[,'col']]
```

Below is what the dataframe looks like:

```
> df
    For  Back SLeft SRight Direction
1   For FALSE FALSE  FALSE     FALSE
2 FALSE FALSE SLeft  FALSE     FALSE
3 FALSE  Back FALSE  FALSE     FALSE
4 FALSE FALSE FALSE SRight     FALSE
```

What I am trying to produce:

```
> df
    For  Back SLeft SRight Direction
1   For FALSE FALSE  FALSE       For
2 FALSE FALSE SLeft  FALSE     SLeft
3 FALSE  Back FALSE  FALSE      Back
4 FALSE FALSE FALSE SRight    SRight
```

With this code:

```
for (i in df){
  for (index in 1:length(i)){
    if (i[index]!="FALSE"){
      df$Direction[i] = i[index]
    }
  }
}
```

What I am getting:

```
> df
    For  Back SLeft SRight Direction
1   For FALSE FALSE  FALSE     FALSE
2 FALSE FALSE SLeft  FALSE     FALSE
3 FALSE  Back FALSE  FALSE     FALSE
4 FALSE FALSE FALSE SRight     FALSE
```

First post, have mercy on my description/edits

Answer (score 1):

We can use row/column indexing to extract the values.  The column index is derived from `max.col`, `cbind` it with row index, extract the values and assign it to create 'Direction'

```
df$Direction <- df[1:4][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), max.col(df[1:4] != FALSE, 'first'))]
df
#    For  Back SLeft SRight Direction
#1   For FALSE FALSE  FALSE       For
#2 FALSE FALSE SLeft  FALSE     SLeft
#3 FALSE  Back FALSE  FALSE      Back
#4 FALSE FALSE FALSE SRight    SRight
```

---

If it was only a logical matrix, then also the `max.col` to create the column index would work and is faster

```
df$Direction <- names(df)[1:4][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), max.col(df[1:4], 'first'))]
```

Comment: Wanted to use `max.col` but you had used it!! Nice

Comment: I am returning all TRUE values instead of the names of the header.

Comment: @TomKim  Please check the `str` of your dataset.  In the first case, I am assume the columns as `character` class and in second, it is `logical`.  Also, you need `names(df)[1:4]` (sorry about that)  Fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Data frame columns have to have a class, like numeric, character, factor, or logical. You had nice columns of logical class, and you should keep them that way!

"*I converted the TRUE values into the header names and made them all characters*" - this was a really bad idea. Don't do this step, and the rest will be easy. `FALSE` and `TRUE` are useful and have good meaning as logical values. As characters, `"FALSE"` and `"TRUE"` are more difficult to work with and will cause confusion when they don't behave like logicals.

If you still had `TRUE` and `FALSE`, then your solution would be

```
df$Direction = names(df)[apply(df, 1, which)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, and the solution worked perfectly!

Comment: Hey Gregor, I tried running this, and the second time I am running into an error of invalid subscript type 'list'. Do you know why this would happen/how to remedy this? I know this isn't part of the original question, but any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you have rows with more than one `TRUE` value - those rows will return more than one name, and so `apply` can't simplify the result to a vector anymore, it falls back on a `list` instead. You could clean your data, or you could probably just change `which` to `which.max`, which will return the index of the *first* TRUE in the row.

Answer (score 1):

```
 transform(df,Direction=df[(s<-which((df!=F),T))[order(s[,1]),]])
    For  Back SLeft SRight Direction
1   For FALSE FALSE  FALSE       For
2 FALSE FALSE SLeft  FALSE     SLeft
3 FALSE  Back FALSE  FALSE      Back
4 FALSE FALSE FALSE SRight    SRight
```